# Any way to get English translations into the dictionaries Windows IME uses?

Tags: discussion

I have my Windows 10 laptop set up with support for Japanese input using Windows' IME.

As you all know, that works quite nicely, until you are trying to input a word using Hiragana and the IME gives you multiple options based on different Kanji.

Let's say I enter　いって, trying go get it written properly using Kanji, but don't know whether 言って, 入って, or 行って is the correct way of writing based on what I mean to say (とる is of course another good example).

The IME gives me this dictionary-based help, but as a learner of Japanese this of course doesn't help much:

[image: IME]

Is there any way to add a Japanese-English to the "standard" Japanese-Japanese dictionary IME uses?

I searched quite a bit for help on this topic, I'm not finding anything. Maybe I'm not looking in the right place or searching with the right keywords...

Thanks in advance for any pointers,

Stephan

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought this was impossible, but after some digging I found [this short article](http://nihongo.online/index.php/tools/1-englishime) which says otherwise.

To use this:

- Download [Google's IME](https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/ime/). The page is in Japanese, but the big blue
  button says 'download'.
- After installing, go to your language settings in Windows, and add it
  as a keyboard for Japanese (Settings > Time and language > region and
  language > 日本語 > Add keyboard).
- Activate the IME, and go to the settings. Go to Dictionary > Edit
  user dictionary > tools > import as current dictionary, and then select
  the [extracted text file linked in the article](http://e-nihon.net/japanese/IME/IMEdict_large.zip) as the file location.
- After a short wait, the IME will have imported all the words, and
  definitions will show in English.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tried installing the Google IME and importing the dictionary file which seem to have worked fine. Unfortunately it doesn't help with the original example (いって). It knows 行って, 言って, and 入って, but not their English translations. Maybe the dictionary is kind of small.

Comment: Well, it does show them for me. They show when you wait a second with an option highlighted in the list. If that doesn't work, then check the imported dictionary again - it should show a list of all the words that were imported. Also, maybe check that you do have Google IME activated, and not windows; The two look largely identical in use.